# Are there any tabletop RPGs in which players advance along a technology tree in the course of the game?

Tags: game-recommendation

There are many video games that involve a player constructing an industrial base and improving their technology (Factorio comes to mind). Are there any tabletop RPGs that incorporate a similar mechanic?

Comment: We don't really do recommendation questions anymore. (The tag, if you check its wiki, will tell you it's no longer on topic). As such, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Got it, thanks for letting me know.